# The default is not showing in the table if no entry is entered?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table that auto increments the Primary key and sets all values to default if nothing is entered into a column. It worked when i did not have the auto increment but it is now not working. What do I have to change to make the word 'Empty' appear in the cell.

Code Here:

```
create table Persons
 (
 P_Id int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
 LastName  varchar(55) default 'Empty',
 FirstName varchar(55) default 'Empty',
 Address   varchar(55) default 'Empty',
 City      varchar(55) default 'Empty'
 )
```

Table:

```
1   l   f   a   c
2   k       l   l
NULL    j   k   NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Working without the auto increment:

```
5   Empty   Empty   Empty   Empty
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

This works then:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AAA](
    [P_Id] [int] NOT NULL primary key,
    [LastName]  [varchar](55) default 'E',
    [FirstName] [varchar](55) default 'E',
    [Address]   [varchar](55) default 'E',
    [City]      [varchar](55) default 'E'
)
```

Working Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Pers
 (
 P_Id int primary key NOT NULL,
 LastName  varchar(55) DEFAULT 'A',
 FirstName varchar(55) DEFAULT 'B',
 Address1  varchar(55) DEFAULT 'C',
 City      varchar(55) DEFAULT 'D' <-- This Will Work (actual all of them do)
 )
```

Why will they not work if the identity(1,1) is set? I need to have a primary key and then I want to set the fields to E for empty or some arbitrary value.

Comment: Why do you want to fill up your database with useless information? That being said the identity has no bearing on this. The columns allow NULL so you can explicitly enter a NULL. If you don't include a column in an insert it will put 'Empty' in there. What is the insert statement you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to not allow **null** values

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons](
    [P_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](55) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](55) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](55) NOT NULL,
    [City] [varchar](55) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Persons__A3420A572F10007B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [P_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Persons__LastNam__30F848ED]  DEFAULT ('Empty') FOR [LastName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Persons__FirstNa__31EC6D26]  DEFAULT ('Empty') FOR [FirstName]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Persons__Address__32E0915F]  DEFAULT ('Empty') FOR [Address]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Persons__City__33D4B598]  DEFAULT ('Empty') FOR [City]
GO
```

Comment: Well, I ran it and it created the table but does not put empty in the tables when I do not entr a value. What does a constraint do with primary key clustered. Is there a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Why don't check the value in code or in SP before execute query?

Comment: Could this be set to null. Why is that Identity(1,1) will not then set the column table. I have not seen many that are this complex to created but I am sort of new to the database SQL.